# IBM Bluemix: Watson Q&A service setup

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

i am trying to run the example java code for the Q&A starter application from

https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-full-java.shtml

i see this error in my project's Markers view

[image]

note that i am still able to run the application but when i hit the Ask button, i get

[image]

Please advise on how i can properly set up my project.

**EDIT**

i can see that i have liberty installed

[image]

is this the correct plugin i should be installing?

also in my targeted runtimes for the project

[image]

and my project facets

[image]

finally, my java build path

[image]

i know its a lot of information but i am really struggling with the set up here.

any help is appreciated.

**EDIT2**

here is what i see in my project servers

[image]

in the server view, when i try to add a new server, i see these options

[image]

is that how it should be ?

further, do i need to enable any of the following websphere options in my project facets?

[image]

ok, so after much struggle i was able to set up my liberty profile correctly. but now when i hit the Ask button, i get

[image]

and here is the piece of code that causes it

```
    JSONObject questionJson = new JSONObject();
```

but why, i have all the imports properly set up and i do not see any compilation errors?

**Another EDIT**

Please tell me if i am missing anything

here is a view of my servers

[image]

and here is a view of my targeted runtimes

[image]

and here is my build path

[image]

Am i missing something? Could this be causing the aforementioned NoClassDefFound error ?

**Server.xml**

[image]

How can i get all the requisite features in my server?

Comment: Are you trying to run it locally or in Bluemix?

Comment: i tried running locally and on bluemix

Comment: did you install any Liberty servers in your Eclipse instance?

Comment: yes, i think i did. i followed the documentation. how would i check if the servers were installed properly ?

Comment: if you want to use Bluemix with Eclipse you have to install Bluemix plugins to Eclipse. For local test you need to install local copy of Liberty

Comment: Also you need to specify the server when you create you problem. Was your project a dynamic web project?

Comment: yes its a dynamic web project. i also installed the eclipse bluemix plugin. is there a way to test/see if the server was properly set up
?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92509/discussion-between-alex-da-silva-and-user2334092).

Comment: thanks Alex, but i cannot access chat right now at my workplace

Comment: OK - no problem. I see German is helping you now

Comment: cool. but i dont understand why i get a class not found for JSON object.

Comment: please see the latest edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have liberty installed. The project is expecting that has target.

Here you have a guide on how to install liberty profile in eclipse: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-eclipse/

Once you have it installed you will need to create a server and deploy the app in that server.

Eclipse has a good [guide](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwcrtins.html) on how to create servers.

**UPDATE:** If you have liberty installed, set it as server and make sure it is as target runtime too. See [this](http://g.recordit.co/cruCL86kUI.gif) animated gif.

Comment: please see the edit. i can see that liberty is installed

Comment: I added an animated gif with the things you need to do. http://g.recordit.co/cruCL86kUI.gif

Comment: cool ! thanks. please see the edit2 for my servers. i do not see the same server as you have displayed in your gif. is it just because you are developing on MAC?

Comment: In the last image you have, add the liberty server and deploy the app there.

Comment: you mean the second option? but i already have such a server added

Comment: i have added another image, please take a look

Comment: hi, i was able to set up the profile correctly, but now i run into a different error. please see the latest part

Comment: Check the gif I've created. Seems like the application can't find a jar that is part of the liberty target.

Comment: hi German, i have the target runtime and build paths set up correctly. where else would i need to specify the JARs?

Comment: 1. server and target should have liberty server selected. 2. The jars lin the lib folder should be included in the classpath.

Comment: so liberty server is different from WAS liberty profile? how do i get that? how do i include the jars in my classpath? i thought that all i had to do for that was to add them in the java build path

Comment: 1. Liberty/WAS are the same. 2. Adding to the build-path is part of adding them to the classpath. Make sure that json is in the features pack for the liberty server you have: http://i.imgur.com/dnPxuI7.png

Comment: thanks! but i see that my view is different from yours. please see the edit. what do i need to do in order to get all the features installed?

Comment: did you click on "add"?

Comment: ok, i was able to add the json feature. but now i get connection timeout error Error: Connect to stream.watsonplatform.net:443 [stream.watsonplatform.net/23.246.237.53] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92767/discussion-between-german-attanasio-and-abtpst).

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately, i cant use chat at work as the chat website is barred here

Comment: why would i be getting a connection timeout?

Comment: thanks for the help German. i have opened up another question for the connection timeout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237872/cannot-connect-to-gateway-watsonplatform-net443

would be great if you can help me out there as well :)